# JQuery Mobile UI DatePicker define date format

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, datepicker

I'm trying to select date in mobile version website but it takes date from `datepicker` in form of `mm/dd/yyyy` but i want it in `dd/mm/yyyy`

I also tried it by changing in "jquery.ui.datepicker.mobile.js" file

```
$( ".ui-page" ).live( "pagecreate", function(){     
   $( "input[type='date'], input[data-type='date']" ).each(function(){
      $(this).after($("<div />").datepicker({ altField: "#" + $(this).attr("id"),
                           showOtherMonths: true, dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" }));
   }); 
});
```

IN my JSP page I write this line

```
<input type="date" id="frmdatepicker" name="frmDateFilter" 
                                          value="<%= frmDateFilter %>"/>
```

but still not working. please help me..

Answer (score 2):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/ZenxF/

This is how you do it:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '[data-role="page"]', function(){ 
   $( "input[type='date']" ).each(function(){
      $(this).datepicker({ altField: "#" + $(this).attr("id"), showOtherMonths: true, dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
   });        
});
```